# Space filling problem with equal radii on earth

Tags: general-topology, geometry, circles

I have two circles. Both origin at San francisco $(37.77493,-122.419415)$, The larger circle has Radius $R_1$, the smaller circle has radius of $R_2$.

What's the fewest number of additional overlapping smaller circles (/w Radius of $R_2$) that fit inside the larger one, that creates zero empty space (except near the edge of the larger circle), and the corresponding co-ordinates of each circle's origin.

I've bounced this problem across my peers, and we've decided that the circles are optimally fitted to how the Flower of Life is laid (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flower_of_Life).

Thus one unit of $R$ from the centre would produce $7$ circles ($1$ in the middle, and $6$ surrounding).

Origin = $(x,y)$

Surrounding circles: (x+cos(60x)R,y+sin(60x)R) // Guess
[image]

From here I'm stuck on how to continue to fill the circle, and how to give real-world coordinates of each of the circle's origins. With input like $R_1 = 5,000$ meters, and $R_2 = 1000$ meters.

Comment: It would help if you were more specific about what you want.  It's not clear to me *exactly how much space* you want to cover with your overlapping small circles considering that the flower of life has a good bit of empty space around the edges.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, empty space around the edges are fine.

Comment: If empty space is fine then I would say the fewest number of additional circles that meet your criteria is $0$.  But I'm certain that's not what you intend, hence I still think you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates of all the centers are:
$$
(\frac{\sqrt{3}j}{2},k + \frac j 2) R
$$
for $k,j$ integers.

To check if the small circle (radius R) is inside the larger one (radius R_1) compute the distance between the centers:
$$
  R \sqrt{\frac 3 4 j^2 + (k+\frac j 2)^2} \le R_1 - R.
$$

Comment: This is true in a flat plane -- but the OP apparently wants the inside of a circle _on a sphere_ to be filled.

Comment: @Henning, with the largest radius just $5$ kilometers, the Earth is pretty nearly flat. But perhaps OP could clarify.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Huh. Were there concrete values for the radii in the question when I commented? Yes, it looks so. Okay then.

Comment: It was an example, but it's a good estimation. Wouldn't be too hard to incorporate haversine, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula thank you.